# Rails 4 - Displaying a dependent model in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an Article model, with a dependent model Photocup. Each Photocup instance has an image attached (using paperclip/imagemagick). I followed the rails guide for adding a second model, the same way Comments are associated with an Article.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model

It works fine. But I want more control over how the Photocups are displayed. I've created a partial _gallery.html.erb in Views/Article. The gallery partial looks like this:

```
  Photo Gallery
 <table class="table2">
 <%= render @article.photocups %>
 </table>
```

_photocup.html.erb in Views/Photocup looks like this"

```
 <td>
 <%= photocup.label %>
 <br> 
 <%= image_tag photocup.image(:small) %>
 <br>
  <%= link_to 'Remove Photo', [photocup.article, photocup],
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
 </td>
```

Works fine, but I can't figure out how to add in a row!

Is there anyway to display the Photocups for the Article I'm looking at the way one does with non-dependent model? For example, an index page would typically have something like this"

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <th>Title</th>
 </tr>
 <%= @photocups.each do |photocup| %>
 </tr>
 <td><%= photocup.title %></td>
 <% end %> 
 </table>
```

Could this be done on the show.html.erb page for the article somehow? Could it be done if I created a partial in Views/Photocup?

If it matters, the route looks like this:

```
 resources :articles do
 resources :comments
 resources :photocups
 get 'gallery' 
 get 'showall'
 get 'feature', on: :collection
 end
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be on the `articles#show` page. Provided your associations are done correctly, you have a:

```
#article.rb
Class Article > ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :photocups
end
```

and

```
#photocup.rb
Class Photocup > ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :article 
end
```

You'll have to declare an instance variable under the show action in the Articles controller. It'll look something like this:

```
#articles_controller.rb
def show
         @article=Article.find(params[:id])
         @photocups=@article.photocups
    end
```

Then use the code for your example index view in your show view and it should show the rows you are seeking.

Also, side note, this line:

```
<%= @photocups.each do |photocup| %>
```

in your example index page does not need an `=`. Those should be reserved for things you want the user to see in the view, it should be:

```
<% @photocups.each do |photocup| %>.
```