# FriendlyID Controller names validates inclusion issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, friendly-id, write-once

Basically I have an app(using devise), where a user signs up `registrations#new` with just an email and password; this registers and creates the user. It immediately takes them to `registrations#edit` where they enter the rest of their information.

I am using a `:name` attribute with friendly_id for vanity urls. This attribute has 3 requirements:

1. It must be written once but unchangeable after it is written.
2. It can not be any of the controller names (or it will break the app).
3. It is unique

For #2
So I added the following validation to my model:
`

```
  validates :name, :exclusion => { :in => %w(
  admin cars registrations users
 ), :message => "Sorry \"%{value}\" is taken!"}`
```

For #3
I added
`validates_uniqueness_of :name`

For #1
I have the following in my view under registrations#edit:

```
<% if @user.name.blank?%>
                <br>
                <h2>Choose your username</h2>
            
                    <%= f.input :name,  :value => "Username" , required: true, autofocus: true, label:false, class: 'usernameinputc'  %>
           
<br>
```

This effectively hides it from the user if it doesn't exist. The problem I am having is that if they enter a controller name as their `:name` or something already taken it will give a devise error, and send them back but the field will be hidden. If i remove the conditional then it allows them to change their `:name` even if it was valid? How can i make it so it shows only if the name attribute hasn't saved?

Note: I tried `if @user.name.persisted?` it gave me a no method error for nilClass(I think because `:name` didn't exist.

## UPDATE

So I have tried to add it as a virtual attribute, I have added a field :username to my permitted params as a virtual attribute. Having a little bit of trouble with the getter and setter methods. I tried this:

```
def username
  self.name if  self.name.persisted?
end
```

I still get a no method error.

Comment: On your update, duh, because you are calling `#persisted?` on a nil value! `#persisted?` is a method of ActiveRecord, not String! That's not what you want to do anyways, because you want to keep `.name` separate from `.username` until you finally save.

Comment: So like I've said I've never used virtual attributes before any chance you could write me an example? My stack overflow answers usually look like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822006/rails-4-displaying-a-dependent-model-in-a-table/31825679#31825679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try this?  This will validate your name against the black list, but also sets the user.name to blank when this happens.  This way your erb will still render correctly.

```
  validate do |user|
    if %w(admin cars registrations users).include?(user.name)

      user.errors[:name] << "Sorry \"" + user.name + "\" is taken!"
      user.name = ""
    end
  end
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a virtual attribute to hold the value in the form.

```
attr_accessor :desired_name
```

When the form is submitted, `User.desired_name` will be filled in. Then perform your validations on the value. If it passes, then copy the virtual attribute to the database field attribute and save and re-direct. (Or copy the value, validate, and if there is an error, set `.name` back to null.) If the real field is not empty, then hide the form.

You should know that is almost a security risk to only hide the form. You should verify in your `#update` method that there is not already an existing value for `.name`, because a hacker can create their own form and submit the value to change it.

Here is a tutorial on virtual attributes: http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes

Comment: I've never really used a virtual attribute, could you give me an example of how i would do it?

Comment: @ChiefrockaChris Updated.

Comment: @ChiefRockaChris `attr_accessor` is part of Ruby language and is definitely NOT deprecated

Comment: @MichalSzyndel That was likely the wrong word sorry, I've removed my comment. I've just been taught that in Rails 4 strong_params is a better approach. I really am just having trouble figuring out how best to do this. While the railscast was helpful, I'm still having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: @ChiefRockaChris strong params are replacement for (now deprecated method) `attr_accessible`. This is not the same as `attr_accessor` which is part of Ruby language. Rails made an unfortunate name collision in here. Anyway - don't worry, we all make mistakes! :)